apt-get not working in windows teamcity build
I have a simple docker file that installs curl for my container
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0
run apt-get -y update; apt-get -y install curl
WORKDIR /app
COPY ["bin/Release/net6.0/", "."]

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Test.Api.Rest.dll"]

I am able to build the image and run locally. But when I try to build through teamcity docker, I am presented with
'apt-get' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
May I ask how do I get around this?

That's probably because you teamcity docker is a Windows docker engine.

@Philippe yes that's definitely the reason. But I require my containers to be deployed on linux machine, unforutnately it's built on a windows machine. And I require the container to have curl command.
